# mobile site redirect with full site link

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I'm using the javascript version from http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ to redirect to a mobile site.  The only thing is that I have a link to go to the full site in the off chance that users want/need to go there.

However, when you click on the link to view the full site from the mobile, it picks back up on the redirection and kicks it back to the mobile version and not to the full site.

I was doing some searching and was wondering if it could be possible to hack it so that it uses

```
window.location.href.indexOf
```

or somthing of that nature like this:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("mobile/index.html") > -1)
{window.location = "http://thefullsiteURL.com"}
else { function (a, b) {
if (//mobile direction stuff from detectmobilebrowsers.com
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera,
'http://thefullsiteURL.com/mobile/index.html')};
```

Keep in mid that this is something that I pieced together and my JS skills are fairly new, so if any one has a more elegant solution I am all for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a session cookie in conjunction with a querystring value in your full site link. Then, have your mobile detect code check first for the cookie value, second for the query string, and last for user agent mobile detect.

So your full site link should be something like with the query string trigger:

```
<a href='http://mysite.com?fullsite=true'>Link to full site</a>
```

And then in your mobile detect:

```
;(function(a,b) {

    if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        return; // skip redirect
    }
    if (location.search.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
        document.cookie = 'fullsite=true; path=/;'
        return; // skip redirect
    } 
    if (/mobile regex conditional goes here/) {
        window.location = b;
    }
})(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://thefullsiteURL.com/mobile/index.html')
```

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I am attempting to throw it all together, but I am not sure what would be causing it to error out.  I have it in this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ultraloveninja/8KYC5/1/

Comment: My original answer just sketched out the logic. I updated it above to make it complete and you should now be able to drop it in. **N.B.** you need to paste in the lenghty mobile detect regex conditional in the last if-statement.