# How do I direct mobile users to a mobile site only once?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, mobile

I would like to direct users coming to my site on a mobile device to a mobile website. Simple enough, just add this script to the header of my home-page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "mobile-site-url";
    }
</script>
```

However, on my mobile site, I want to give users the option of going to the full site. How do I do that? The script above redirects them every time they try to access the page on a mobile device.

How do I only redirect them the first time, but not when they click on the "visit the full site" link on the mobile site?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add a parameter to the URL like "?showdesktop=true" with the "go to desktop" link and have this override the redirection.

Comment: Also, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12150267/1979005) for a great solution. It uses cookies in conjunction with the URL query string.