# Part II Newbie creating a function for a redirect

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

Thanks for all your help. I still can't seem to get this to work write. Chrome likes the fact that the return statements are in a function. But it still doesn't want to work right. The code still redirects to the mobile site when I click on any links on the full site. Maybe I am not setting the cookie right on the mobile site?

```
<script>
var expires = new Date();
expires.setHours(expires.getHours + 1); 
document.cookie = (document.cookie ? document.cookie + ' ;' : '')
     + ' disableMobile=1; expires=' + expires.toGMTString();
</script>
```

This is the link:

```
<p class="site"><a href="http://production.bayareacrimlaw.com/?fullsite=true">Visit our     full site: bayareacrimlaw.com</a></p>
```

This is the code on the full site:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
if (document.cookie.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
    return; // skip redirect
}
if (location.search.indexOf('fullsite') > -1) {
    document.cookie = 'fullsite=true; path=/;'
    return; // skip redirect
}
(function(a, b) {
    if (/android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|meego.+mobile|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0, 4))) window.location = b
})
        (navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera, 'http://mobile.bayareacrimlaw.com/');
})();
</script>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Why not just use a media query and if pixel dimensions are < BLAHpx redirect to mobile ?

Comment: The boss wants a site like the mobile version of Southwest Airlines. He wants to have users access the fullsite from the mobile site. It is a huge pain. I did use media queries to make the site viewable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is exactly what you need my friend- 
Mobile redirect the allows you to go to full site without redirecting back to mobile. 
It was on a similar post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144775/mobile-site-redirect-with-full-site-link)

Comment: Hmmm...I can't seem to get it to work. But, thanks for adding more.